# search query function of md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete, md-chip

Angular material documentation for md-autocomplete for tags(md-chips) uses a filter function given below-

```
    //Search for vegetables.
    function querySearch (query) {
      var results = query ? self.vegetables.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
      return results;
    }

    //Create filter function for a query string
     function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
       return function filterFn(vegetable) {
          return (vegetable._lowername.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0) ||
            (vegetable._lowertype.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
       };
     }
```

source: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

Can someone please explain these two functions ? 
In querySearch method, what does "self.vegetables.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];" mean?

("vegetables" is the array of all objects out of which suggestions will be given and query is the search text)

Answer (score 0):

```
function querySearch (query) {
      var results = query ? self.vegetables.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
      return results;
    }
```

if the query is not empty , it's return the vegetables list but if query is empty it's return void

```
//Create filter function for a query string
     function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
       return function filterFn(vegetable) {
          return (vegetable._lowername.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0) ||
            (vegetable._lowertype.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
       };
     }
```

the function first lowercase the query string and check if the query is in the list